# Mixing static and dynamic libraries in fedora

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

There are already some answers how to mix dynamic and static linking of binaries.
Like in the anwers I read so far I compile like this:

```
gcc main.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lc -Wl,-Bdynamic -lmyshared_lib -L. libx.a liby.a
```

But then I get an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libpthread.a(libpthread.o): In function `sem_open':
(.text+0x6407): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The third-party lib is itself dependend on libc.so.6, so I guess this is now in conflict with my static linked libc.
If I compile with the -fPIE and -pie parameters like below - the application segfaults immediately:

```
gcc main.cpp -fPIE -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -lstdc++ -lpthread -lrt -lc -Wl,-Bdynamic -lmyshared_lib -L. libx.a liby.a -Wl,-pie
```

Does it even work to compile nearly completely static and just link one shared object additionally?

I try to do this because I want to get one specific 32bit binary to run on a x64 system using a 32bit third party shared object...

Comment: 1) it is possible to have a mixed linking
2) it seems that you are trying to link `libx.a` and `liby.a` static libraries dynamically, perhaps move them to static section?
3) try to move pthread to dynamic -- this is one is very complicated.

Comment: 1) that's right
2) if one specifies the absolute path to the static lib it's linked statically
3) thanks for that - if I move pthread and libc to dynamic linking I get no errors, but originally I wanted to remove those deps for the application. After a second thought it makes not much sense because the .so has a libc.so dependency anyway.